# How to force the notifications of Defender Firewall using GPO?

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

I am preparing a set of GPO to harden W10. I enabled the Defender firewall blocking most of the connections but I also wanted to leave the notifications for helping me with the fine tuning of the settings. So I can get feedback of flows and applications that might need to be allowed. [Firewall notification message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEs8f.png)

I already tried with the following settings

```
Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Private Profile\Settings Display a notification YES
    Computer Configuration / Policies / Admin templates Network\Network Connections\Windows Defender Firewall\Domain Profile Windows Defender Firewall: Prohibit notifications Disabled
    Computer Configuration / Policies / Admin templates Windows Components\Windows Defender Security Center\Notifications Hide all notifications Disabled
    Computer Configuration / Policies / Admin templates Windows Components\Windows Defender Security Center\Notifications Hide non-critical notifications Disabled
```

and the setting appears grey out with the message "this setting is managed by your system administrator". But the notification appears set to off(!). [Firewall notification settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3TcL.jpg) Any idea why this could happen? is there any other setting I should tweak to achieve my goal?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mistery solved for now.

At the end, I think I found a little bug in the Firewall GPO.

> Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security
>   Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Windows Firewall
>   with Advanced Security\Domain Profile\Settings Display a notification
>   --> **No Configured**
>
> Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security
>   Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Windows Firewall
>   with Advanced Security\Private Profile\Settings Display a notification
>   --> **No Configured**
>
> Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security
>   Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Windows Firewall
>   with Advanced Security\Public Profile\Settings Display a notification
>   --> **No Configured**

If you choose "Yes", then the check box appears disabled and grey out. (!)

The other two settings for the Security Center remained as it was.

> Computer Configuration / Policies / Admin templates Windows
>   Components\Windows Defender Security Center\Notifications Hide all
>   notifications **Disabled**
>
> Computer Configuration / Policies / Admin templates Windows
>   Components\Windows Defender Security Center\Notifications Hide
>   non-critical notifications **Disabled**